# Assets {if caption} breaks if caption has " or ' in it

Tags: assets, add-on, bug

I'm thinking this is a bug and just needs some addslashes to it. Anyone else run across this problem? I've tried:

```
{if caption}
{if '{caption}'}
{if "{caption}"}
{if '{caption}' != ''}
```

Even used it within an assets loop with var_prefix with all above options:
{if img:caption}

None of them are 100% fool-proof. If the caption has one ' it breaks one method; if it has two, it breaks another. Frustrating.

EE 2.7.0
Assets 2.2.2

Parse error: parse error in ../system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code on line 135

Comment: Not normal I don't think. Assets and EE version?

Comment: It appears as though the culprit may be ’ vs ' or "...

Comment: I suggest you to fill a bug report.